# ImageResizer license for image compression only

Tags: licensing, imageresizer

We want to use ImageResizer in our "software as a service" solution to compress user-uploaded images before saving them on the server. We will not use it to serve the images.

Do we need a caching plugin?

Can we use the free version for this, or we need to buy a license?

If the license is required, what license should we get? (we run DNN install with 50+ portals)

p.s. @Nathaniel Jones responded to my support ticket, and said that it's ok to use the free version in our setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ImageResizer's [SaaS license](http://imageresizing.net/licenses/saas) is what you are looking for.

In a large deployment, the Apache-licensed Essential edition lacks some important features, the most popular of which are:

- HQ Gif  and Animated Gif support
- The higher-quality image resizing/rendering engine [FastScaling](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/fastscaling), which is [43x faster as well](http://imageresizing.net/blog/2015/v4highlights).
- Blob storage support. Unless you plan to store everything on local disks, you need a flexible data store.
- FreeImageDecoder adds support for RAW & HDR source images - over 20 formats supported.

The SaaS license is flat-fee, royalty free, and includes an Enterprise-wide Elite license as well.

Comment: I understand that SaaS license has all these extra features, but we're happy with that "free" version provides. Can we use it?